# My Cat Meows at Me Every Morning

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, vocalizations

I wake up at 6:30 every morning and when I get out of bed, I hear an insane amount of meows. When I get into the shower, she sits right next to the tub and cries at me. I open the door so she can go outside, check her litter box and feed her, but she won’t stop! It doesn’t really bother me. I just want to make sure she is okay. Thank you!

Comment: So she do not cry for food? (Because you wrote "check her litter box and feed her") If she get new food after you finished morning routine, you should have a look to this question: [Cat meows for wet food but has dry food available](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20795/cat-meows-for-wet-food-in-morning-despite-dry-food-being-available)

Comment: FYI have a look to this question too: [Cat meows insistently when I shower](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/why-does-my-cat-insistently-meow-at-me-when-i-shower?)

Comment: Has your car always done this? Or has it started recently?

Answer (score 3):

Aw, maybe your cat just wants some attention and hugs from you :) 
 My guess is, she is just saying something like: "good morning, I'm so happy you are awake and can spend time with me now :3" 
But then you take a shower and the cat still wants attention, so she keeps meowing.
You could try to cuddle with her for like 5 minutes after you got up in the morning, talk to her, pet her and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to give her lots of cuddles in the morning.

Comment: @JoleePitts I would say its worth a try :) I'm sure you can figure it out

Comment: But if the behavior will become more difficult, it could be the case that you train your cat to meow for cuddles, until she will not left you a minute of peace

Comment: @Allerleirauh I get your point. Maybe one just need to cuddle the cat even more :)

Answer (score 3):

I have two cats - one of them loves to meow at us in the morning, and the other is very quiet throughout the day.

This is not a metaphor - this is just a way of explaining that cats are all different and will have different behavior depending on their personality.

Our cat that meows more has a lot of different reasons to meow - sometimes they are hungry, sometimes they are bored, sometimes their litterbox needs an extra cleaning, and sometimes they just want some attention.

Most likely if it's early morning, your cat just wants attention, or might be begging for their food bowl to be full - but overall, there really isn't a cause for concern here.  If anything, it just shows that your cat trusts you and knows they can come to you when they need something.

---

One more thing - sometimes the time at which cats will meow can be inconvenient.  Our talkative cat used to meow and bang at our bedroom door late at night.  It is important that you do not give into this type of behavior, or they will learn that they can get what they want when they do this.